# Apache FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(String) returns null

Tags: java, inputstream, ftp-client

I am using Java 11 and SpringBoot.  I am trying to create a FTPClient to read files from an existing FTP server.  Using Apache [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

**Problem:**

```
InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());
```

The following always returns a `null` InputStream.

**Info:**

```
logger.info("File name: "+file.getName()+", type: "+file.getType()+", size: "+file.getSize()+".");
```

returns:

> File name: cam_test, type: 1, size: 28.

**Question:**

You can see that there is a file called 'cam_test', why can't this be converted into an InputStream?

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public void processFiles() {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftp.connect(IP_ADDRESS);

        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

        logger.info("Connected to " + IP_ADDRESS + ". ReplyCode: '"+reply+"'.");
        if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            logger.error("FTP server ('"+IP_ADDRESS+"') refused connection.");
        } else {
            // transfer files
            ftp.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles(BASE_DIR);
            logger.info("Connected to " + IP_ADDRESS + ". Got '"+files.length+"' files from working directory: "+ftp.printWorkingDirectory()+BASE_DIR+".");
            for (FTPFile file : files) {
                logger.info("File name: '"+file.getName()+"', type: '"+file.getType()+"', size: '"+file.getSize()+"', directory: '"+file.isDirectory()+"', file: '"+file.isFile()+"'.");
                if (file.isFile() && 0 == file.getType()) {
                    InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());  // <--- is always null
                    processFile(file, is);
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    boolean completePendingCommand = ftp.completePendingCommand();
                    logger.info("completePendingCommand: "+completePendingCommand);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if(ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ftp.disconnect();
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you are missing a call to completePendingCommand . In Javadocs: "To finalize the file transfer you must call completePendingCommand and check its return value to verify success. If this is not done, subsequent commands may behave unexpectedly. "

Comment: Hi @pringi, thank you for your reply.  I will add `completePendingCommand` as you suggest because it looks like a valid check.  But this is done after the inputStream is retrieved as null, so it has no affect.

Comment: Type 1 is a directory (public static final int DIRECTORY_TYPE = 1;). I think that this is the problem. Check with file.isDirectory()

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, it is a directory: `File name: 746, type: 1, size: 48, directory: true, file: false.`

Comment: I still get a `null` InputStream with the following:  `File name: '746_CLHO_01FEB22.csv', type: '0', size: '1748955', directory: 'false', file: 'true'.`.

Comment: You should check null before processFile.

Comment: I do check for `null` in the `processFile` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242153/discussion-between-pringi-and-richard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `completePendingCommand` after each command.

In the following piece of code completePendingCommand is commented out.

```
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
          System.out.println(
              "File name: " + file.getName() + ", type: " + file.getType() + ", size: " + file.getSize() + ".");
          InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());

          System.out.println(is == null);

//          ftp.completePendingCommand();
        }
```

The result is:

> Connected to ftp.dlptest.com. 220
>
> File name: actorstoday.txt, type: 0,
> size: 0.
> false
>
> File name: actorstomorrow.txt, type: 0, size: 0.
> true

As you an see the second request is returning a null InputStream.

Changing to:

```
for (FTPFile file : files) {
  System.out.println(
      "File name: " + file.getName() + ", type: " + file.getType() + ", size: " + file.getSize() + ".");
  InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());

  System.out.println(is == null);

  ftp.completePendingCommand();
}
```

The result is :

> Connected to ftp.dlptest.com. 220
>
> File name: actorstoday.txt, type: 0,
> size: 0.
> false
>
> File name: actorstomorrow.txt, type: 0, size: 0.
> false

In each iteration of the for loop you must call `completePendingCommand`.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me, because the InputStream is still null, even if I call `completePendingCommand`, i.e. `is == null` is always `true`.  (Also, calling `completePendingCommand` causes the thread to hang)

Comment: I have updated my `processFiles()` method above, to show where I call `completePendingCommand` unsuccessfully.

Comment: Call completePendingCommand only if a command was called. In you case only inside of this if (if (file.isFile() && 0 == file.getType()) {). You are always calling it, that's why it blocks.

Comment: That doesn't work, because the `is` is always `null`. Even on the first call.